# How do I use the value from row above when a given column value is zero?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, case-when

I have a table of items by date (each row is a new date).  I am drawing out a value from another column D.  I need it to replace 0s though.  I need the following logic: when D=0 for that date, use the value in column D from the date prior.

Actually, truth be told, I need it to say, when D is 0, use the value from the latest date where D was not a 0, but the first will get me most of the way there.

Is there a way to build this logic?  Maybe a CTE?

Thank you very much.

PS I'm using SSMS 2008.

EDIT: I wasn't very clear at first.  The value I want to change is not the date.  I want change the value in D with the latest non-zero value from D, based on date.

Comment: Its often a good idea when asking questinos like this to provide example data for input, and expected return data. Then we have a clear spec of what is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be the following query might help you. It uses the `OUTER APPLY` to fetch the results. Screenshot #**1** shows the sample data and query output against the sample data. This query can be written better but this is what I could come up with right now.

Hope that helps.

```
SELECT      ITM.Id
        ,   COALESCE(DAT.New_D, ITM.D) AS D
        ,   ITM.DateValue
FROM        dbo.Items   ITM
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT      
                TOP 1       D   AS New_D
                FROM        dbo.Items DAT
                WHERE       DAT.DateValue   < ITM.DateValue
                AND         DAT.D           <> 0
                AND         ITM.D           = 0
                ORDER BY    DAT.DateValue DESC
            ) DAT
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

Comment: That's close to what I want, but I want D to change when it is 0, not DateValue.  Or truly, I want a second column that is D with no 0s.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test right this second, but it looks perfect.  Thank you very much.  And thank you for the example screenshots.  What a great help.  Thank you.

Comment: Pls accept this as the first correct suggestion (which I think it is), but I'd like to see the efficiency comparison with especially my second. I'm generally suspicious of the optimality of anything with "TOP 1" in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t
Set value = SELECT value
              FROM table 
             WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(t1.date)
                             FROM table t1
                            WHERE t1.value != 0
                              AND t1.date < t.date)
 FROM table t
WHERE t.value = 0
```

Comment: When we are using the max then I think, no need to state that t1.date < t.date ?

Comment: if `t1.date < t.date` is removed, it will always get the maximum `date` for all rows (whole table). But he needs the latest date before current row date.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe something like this as part of an update script...

```
SET myTable.D = (
   SELECT TOP 1 myTable2.D 
   FROM myTable2
   WHERE myTable2.myDateField < myTable.myDateField
   AND myTable2.D != 0
   ORDER BY myTable2.myDateField DESC)
```

That's assuming that you want to actually update the data though rather than just replace the values for the purpose of a select query.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to update the data.  Though I could just create a second column and update that data.  I am just using it in a select.  Technically, using it to create a view, but same difference.  I don't want to update the DateField though, I want to update column D value.  So for 1/1/10 D would be 13 then for 1/2/10 its 0 and for 1/3/10 its 0 and for 1/4/10 its 19, then 1/2/10 and 1/3/10 would become 13 as well and 1/4/10 would remain 19.

Comment: Oops, I updated the wrong field in the script, I've changed it now!  Although if you don't want to update the data then this isn't really what you need.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT
    i.ID,
    i.DateValue,
    D = CASE WHEN I.D <> 0 THEN I.D ELSE X.D END
FROM
    Items I
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 S.D 
        FROM Items S 
        WHERE S.DATEVALUE < I.DATEVALUE AND S.D <> 0 
        ORDER BY S.DATEVALUE DESC
    ) X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id,
    CASE WHEN t.D = 0 THEN t0.D
         ELSE t.D END
FROM table AS t
LEFT JOIN table AS t0
    ON t0.time = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(time) FROM t0
        WHERE t0.time < t.time
        AND t0.D != 0
    )
```

or if you want to avoid aggregates entirely,

```
SELECT t.id,
   CASE WHEN t.D = 0 THEN t0.D
       ELSE t.D END
FROM table AS t
LEFT JOIN table AS t0
    ON t0.time < t.time
LEFT JOIN table AS tx
    ON tx.time > t0.time
WHERE t0.D != 0
    AND tx.D != 0
    AND tx.id IS NULL  -- i.e. there isn't any
```